# What happens to my money if I found a colony in October, November, or December?

Tags: slipways

In the game Slipways, income is calculated at the end of each year. This income is calculated as:

```
I = ΣT(c) - ΣU(c) - nA(n)  (¢)
T = Trade Income per colony
U = Upkeep per colony 
A = Admin cost
n = Number of colonies
```

Trade income is [a complicated formula](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/386981/how-is-planetary-trade-income-determined/386982#386982). Admin cost depends on the number of colonies. For every 8 colonies it goes up by 1¢

Founding a colony takes a total of 3 months time. So what exactly happens if those three months end up overlapping the new year, meaning the action of founding was initiated either in October, November, or December?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, using the Question's notation:

- Since you cannot build any connections to a planet founded near the end of the year, the trade income `T(c) = 0`
- The variable `A(n)` does not increase (it uses the `n` of all completed colonies at the start of the year).
- The variable `n` increases by one.
- `U(n)` applies for an incomplete colony.

This means founding a colony right before the end of the year costs you 1¢ per empire size increase, plus its maintenance cost. However, you do not pay for empire size increases until the year after.

Note that Slipways is currently in Beta status so this mechanic may be subject to change.